# Call a SAP transaction, execute with given parameters and download a report with C# or VB.net

Tags: c#, .net, ui-automation, sap-gui, sap-r3

I'm not familiar with ABAP at all and I'm trying to automate a SAP report for my job (downloaded from the result of an executed transaction in SAP R/3).

At the moment I have to open SAP (manually of course), login, call the transaction, add some parameters to it, execute it and download the first report. After that I have to work it around (thing that I already automate, so it's not a problem) but then I have to get some other parameters from it and call another transaction to execute with the new parameters that I got from the first report... And so on 2 more times.

My problem is that, after automating all the excel related stuff, I can't find a way to interact with SAP R/3 to login, call the transaction, execute with the parameters and get the report with C# or VB.net

Can somebody give me a hint about this?

I googled for a couple of hours and all I found out is that I may have to work with RFC's and BAPI's but I still can't figure out how to do it nor how to use these properly (if I'm right that I have to).

Comment: Yes, that's right.  .NET applications communicate best through the SAP .NET Connector, also known as SAP NCo.  You can [Nuget the DLLs now](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SAPNCo.x86/), I believe, or download them from service.sap.com.  Once you have them, [HERE](http://scn.sap.com/community/interoperability-microsoft-net/blog/2013/02/14/connecting-to-sap-with-nco-3) is a good jumping off point for tutorials.

Comment: After some research I found out that to create a RFC for the Z-Report I gotta have access to SE37. But I don't have access (and won't be granted access neither because I work as a consultant).
Is there ANY way to work with the SAP front end as a windows process and automate the parameters completion and emulate the clicks?

Comment: In short, no there isn't.

Comment: Well actually I discovered yesterday that SAP has a scripting option, with which I can 'record' steps somewhat like a macro (and it even does it in second plane!) so I'm working on VB.net and VBScript to get this done, it's perfectly possible and pretty easy aswell. Thanks anyway @oakfish56 I appreaciated your help

Comment: Seriously?  Craziness... I'll have to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that SAP has a **scripting** option, with which I can 'record' steps somewhat like a macro (and it even does it in second plane!) so I'm working on **VB.NET and VBScript** to get this done, it's perfectly possible and simple aswell.

EDIT: [Introduction to SAP Gui Scripting](http://scn.sap.com/community/gui/blog/2012/10/08/introduction-to-sap-gui-scripting) is what I used as a guide to implement this.